# Google bot .net and AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport dilemma

Tags: .net, session, cookieless

i have a .net mobile web site where i use sesion state and due to nature of mobile networks/phones (not all supports session cookies) i had to use

```
<sessionState cookieless="AutoDetect"/>
```

It works fine but because each new session redirected with "AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1" i have a feeling that google won't like this.

Here is a small sample from my server logs

```
supportForumReadTopic.aspx id=38 80 - 66.249.71.80 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+Googlebot/2.1;++http://www.google.com/bot.html) 302


supportForumReadTopic.aspx id=38&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+Googlebot/2.1;++http://www.google.com/bot.html) 200
```

As you see each new hit from google will get 302 to itself. I have a genericmozilla5.browser file where i define google bot as cookie supporting browser in order to get .net not to use cookieless urls but not sure how this 302 would effect me.

Any one had smilar exprience? Any ideas? Suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just bumped into the same problem, and you are correct, Google is not happy about the redirects. You can confirm it with wget:

```
wget --no-cookies <url>
```

This will lead to a redirection loop.

My solution will probably be to turn off the cookieLess sessions, since I don't really need it. Another solution might be to always use cookieLess sessions, if you really have to support browsers without cookies. This will at least solve the problem, although your URLs will be ugly.